# Como fazer uma barra de progresso do download PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho um site de upload e download de arquivos, quero fazer uma `progress` de download parecido com o do `Mega`, dê uma olhada na página de download: [página](http://www.jmshared.com/rb) .. Já tentei fazer mais não consegui, alguém pode por favor me ajudar?

Comment: Oi, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Por favor confira o guia [ask]. O melhor é você mostrar o que tentou e o que achou durante sua pesquisa sobre o problema.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar a função ajax da jquery ou o plugin form tambem, é bem simples usar o plugin, tenta isso:

**Sobre ajax na jquery você pode ver mais aqui: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/**

**JSFiddle do exemplo do plugin jquery form: http://jsfiddle.net/W3AmK/**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {

var bar = $('.bar');
var percent = $('.percent');
var status = $('#status');

$('form').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {
        status.empty();
        var percentVal = '0%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    success: function() {
        var percentVal = '100%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
        status.html(xhr.responseText);
    }
}); 

})();       
</script>
<div class="progress">
    <div class="bar"></div >
    <div class="percent">0%</div >
</div>

<div id="status"></div>
```